# Method not found: 'Void Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, Autofac.Core.IModule)'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I am getting error like 'Method not found: 'Void Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, Autofac.Core.IModule)' when I updated the latest version of Asp.net MVC Application.

My application are using

1. Autofac.Mvc5
2. Autofac.WebAPI
3. WebAPI2.2 Help Page and other dlls are as well.

After installed Webapi2.2 help-page,I got security issue in Autofac so as per suggestions by google I have updated the latest version of Autofac.

After updating the AutoFac MVC5 and WebAPI versions, I got above error while trying to use RegisterModule more than one times. Please find my code as below

var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterModule(new xyz());

builder.RegisterModule(new abc());

builder.Build();

My config file are as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Autofac" version="4.0.0-beta6-110" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="3.3.4" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="3.4.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.CodeReports" version="0.1.6.4" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.CodeReports.Exporters.Html" version="0.1.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.CodeReports.Exporters.Xlio" version="0.1.5.1" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Common" version="0.5.16.9" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Common.Localization" version="0.5.9.2" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Common.SqlServer" version="0.6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Dextop" version="1.2.0.25" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Dextop.Core" version="1.2.0.40" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Dextop.Preprocessor" version="1.1.0.5" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Xlio" version="0.9.3.21" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse" version="1.8.6" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Ado" version="1.7.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.AspNet" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.EF6" version="1.6.5" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Mvc4" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="HtmlTags" version="2.0.0.181" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Humanizer" version="1.25.4" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
</packages>
```

I tried multiple solution to resolve but not got a success. Could you please pass me the correct solution to resolve?

Thanks

Comment: The signature of RegisterModule changed.  Go look for how to register modules in the latest version of autofac

Comment: Hi Will,Thanks for response. Actually RegisterModule is working fine if I registerd with only one module like var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterModule(new xyz());  builder.Build(); I am gettting error while trying to add more than one module.

Comment: Can you show your packages.config so we can see the versions of things you have installed? Also, do any of your modules register other modules internally?

Comment: Nope, that's not correct at all.  `Method not found: 'Void Autofac.RegistrationExtensions.RegisterModule(Autofac.ContainerBuilder, Autofac.Core.IModule)` means ***the method is not found***.  You don't just *lose* a method between calls.  You can't call it once, then have it fail the next time.  The binder is locating what it thinks is the correct assembly, loading it into the appdomain, and when trying to find that method signature it is failing.  What you believe or are assuming is happening **is not**.  Stop  Go look at the methods on the type.  Use a disassembler if necessary.

Comment: Hi Travis, Please find packages.config file as below, let me know if you need more info <packages xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Autofac" version="3.5.2" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Autofac.Mvc5" version="3.3.4" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi" version="3.1.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Autofac.WebApi2" version="3.4.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />

Comment: <package id="Codaxy.CodeReports" version="0.1.6.4" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.CodeReports.Exporters.Html" version="0.1.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.CodeReports.Exporters.Xlio" version="0.1.5.1" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Common" version="0.5.16.9" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Common.Localization" version="0.5.9.2" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Common.SqlServer" version="0.6.0.2" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />

Comment: <package id="Codaxy.Dextop.Core" version="1.2.0.40" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Dextop.Preprocessor" version="1.1.0.5" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Codaxy.Xlio" version="0.9.3.21" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse" version="1.8.6" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Ado" version="1.7.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.AspNet" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />

Comment: <package id="Glimpse.Ado" version="1.7.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.AspNet" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.EF6" version="1.6.5" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Glimpse.Mvc4" version="1.5.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="HtmlTags" version="2.0.0.181" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Humanizer" version="1.25.4" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" xmlns="" />

Comment: If you have any problem to read please give me your email Id i will pass u config file in an email.

Comment: Please update your question rather than putting it in comments. This is, unfortunately, illegible. Also, again, need the answer to the question I asked: Do you have any modules that register other modules? Finally, please include the full stack trace and message. (All of that should go in the question, please, properly formatted as code so it can be read.)

Comment: Hi Travis added the config file in html format for easy to read in questions.Actually I have started error after updated the latest version of autofac dll. Due to added Webapi2.2 help page in project, i have updated the DLL to resolve the securtiy issue.

Comment: You still haven't included the full stack trace for the message, but I think I see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the reference to `Autofac.WebApi`. You only need `Autofac.WebApi2`. We haven't supported `Autofac.WebApi` for quite some time and it's only for the 3.x and before versions of Web API. `Autofac.WebApi` wasn't updated when the signature on `RegisterModule` changed.

I'm guessing that everything goes swimmingly until you try to register something in a module that uses the old version of `Autofac.WebApi`.